# Infer $||Tf||^2\leq B^2 ||f||^2$ from frame definition.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, frame-theory

A sequence of distinct vectors $\{f_1,f_2,...\}$ belonging to a separable Hilbert space $H$ is said to be a Frame if there exist positive contants $A$, $B$ such that
$$A\|f\|^2\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty |(f,f_n)|^2\leq B \|f\|^2.$$
If we associate with a given frame $\{f_1,f_2,...\}$ a bounded operator $T$ on $H$ defined by
$$Tf=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (f,f_n) f_n$$
it follows
$$(Tf,f)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |(f,f_n)|^2$$

Can we infer
$$||Tf||^2\leq B^2 ||f||^2?$$

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator $T$ is called the *Frame operator*. A simple computation can prove that $T$ is self adjoint. Moreover, $T$ is positive and $AI\leq T\leq BI$, and hence $\|T\|\leq B$. Fix $f\in H$ and suppose $f\neq 0$. Consider $T(f/\|f\|)$. We have

$$\left\| T\left(\frac{f}{\|f\|}\right)\right\|\leq B.$$

Multiplying by $\|f\|$ we obtain $\|T(f)\|\leq B\|f\|$, and hence the result.

**Edit:**

Note that, as you wrote

$$(T(f),f)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |(f,f_n)|^2,$$

and, by assumption

$$A\|f\|^2\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty |(f,f_n)|^2\leq B \|f\|^2.$$

Hence

$$(AI(f),f)=A\|f\|^2\leq(T(f),f)\leq B \|f\|^2=(BI(f),f).$$

This proves that $AI\leq T\leq BI$.

Comment: Added the proof of $AI\leq T\leq BI$.

Comment: thank you! But, why T is self adjoint?

Comment: @Mark Here you can found a proof: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433006/proof-complex-positive-definite-self-adjoint/433021#433021.