# If A and B are PSD, and AB is normal, how to prove that AB is PSD?

Tags: linear-algebra

In the paper [*On a product of positive semidefinite matrices*](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0024379599000142/1-s2.0-S0024379599000142-main.pdf?_tid=699995da-c47e-4c51-b833-33f1c6c8516b&acdnat=1540271659_44a4c330b6bedb09364232783534d28d), page 6, for the proof of (1) - (2): if A and B are PSD, how to draw the conclusion that AB is PSD? Can someone explain in detail?

Answer (score 3):

For a matrix $X$, let $\sigma (X)$ is the set all eigenvalues of $X$.

First note that, $AB=A^{1/2}(A^{1/2}B)$. Thus $\sigma (AB)=\sigma ((A^{1/2}B)A^{1/2})$.
(Since for two matrices X, Y, we have $\sigma(XY)=\sigma(YX)$.)

Since $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ is PSD, it follows that eigenvalues of $AB$ are non-negative.

Finally, since $AB$ is normal, by Spectral theorem $AB=UDU^*$, for some unitary matrix $U$
and diagonal matrix $D$. Since $D$ has non-negative diagonal entries, we conclude that $AB$ is PSD.

Comment: Thank you but I'm still confused about some conclusions relevant to PSD. How do you know that $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ and $UDU^* $ are PSD?

Comment: If $X$ is PSD and $Y$ is any matrix, then $YXY^*$ is always PSD. This follows from the equality $YXY^*=(YX^{1/2})(YX^{1/2})^*$. Let me know if you still have some confusion. Thanks..

Comment: So for $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$, did you use $A^*=A$? But I think A is only PSD, why does it imply that $A^*=A$?

Comment: Can you tell me what is your definition of a PSD matrix?

Comment: For any vector $x$, $x^TAx>=0$, then A is PSD.

Comment: If the matrix is over the filed of the complex numbers (which is the case in the paper you have referred), then $x^TAx\geq 0$ for all $x$ implies $A=A^*$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433006/proof-complex-positive-definite-self-adjoint

Comment: For a PSD matrix $A$, $A = A^*$ means that $A = (\bar{A})^T$. If A only contains real numbers, does that mean $A = A^T$? But a PSD matrix A doesn't have to be symmetric. That's what I'm confused about.